# Why is OrderBy always returning zero to the top?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sum

I have a database which lists countries. Each country may have zero or more breweries, and each brewery zero or more beers. I am sorting the countries into order of how many beers originate from them. To this end, I produce this code:-

```
sorted_countries = db.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.Breweries.Sum(y => y.Beers.Count()));
```

One of the countries in the database has no breweries and this country is at the top of the list, as one would expect. But if I invert the order:-

```
sorted_countries = unsorted_countries.OrderBy(x => -1*x.Breweries.Sum(y => y.Beers.Count()));
```

the country with no breweries still appears at the top of the display.

Why is this so?

It seems to me that if one applies the `.Sum` method to an empty collection, the result should always be zero, and it would sort normally. But it seems always to come first, even if reverse order is selected.

(I can fix the problem easily enough, like this:-

```
sorted_countries = db.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.Breweries.Count() > 0 ? 0 : 1)
                               .ThenBy(x => -1*x.Breweries.Sum(y => y.Beers.Count()));
```

but I am wondering what is going on, and why this is necessary.)

**Edit**

As suggested by Andy G, I tried this:-

```
sorted_countries = db.Countries.OrderByDescending(x => x.Breweries.Sum(y => y.Beers.Count()));
```

The country with no breweries then appears at the bottom of the list as expected (this is a better way of fixing the problem than I had).

**Edit**

As suggested by Jon Skeet, the SQL generated for the "times -1" method is...

```
SELECT [t0].[CountryID], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Code]
FROM [dbo].[Country] AS [t0]
ORDER BY (
    SELECT SUM([t3].[value])
    FROM (
        SELECT @p0 * ((
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM [dbo].[Beer] AS [t2]
            WHERE [t2].[BreweryID] = [t1].[BreweryID]
            )) AS [value], [t1].[CountryID]
        FROM [dbo].[Brewery] AS [t1]
        ) AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[CountryID] = [t0].[CountryID]
    ), [t0].[Name]
```

whereas the OrderByDescending produces:-

```
SELECT [t0].[CountryID], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Code]
FROM [dbo].[Country] AS [t0]
ORDER BY (
    SELECT SUM([t3].[value])
    FROM (
        SELECT (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM [dbo].[Beer] AS [t2]
            WHERE [t2].[BreweryID] = [t1].[BreweryID]
            ) AS [value], [t1].[CountryID]
        FROM [dbo].[Brewery] AS [t1]
        ) AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[CountryID] = [t0].[CountryID]
    ) DESC, [t0].[Name]
```

Comment: What happens in you invert the order by using `OrderByDescending` rather than multiplying by -1?

Comment: @AndyG, aha; now it behaves as one would expect.

Comment: @Sinatr, but -1 * 1 should come before zero in the normal order of things.

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve] that would really help. Did you look at the generated SQL?

Comment: @BrianHooper My answer addresses that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a Country has no Breweries then you are sorting by a `null` value. These are placed first in ascending order using `OrderBy`.

Multiplying by -1 does not change the placement of `null`'s, `OrderByDescending` does.